# JSON payload in shell script using CURL

Tags: json, shell, curl, jq

In my shell script, I'm reading a JSON array from a file. Then I'm looping over the array and send a POST request with each item from the array as json payload;

`data.json`

```json
[
  {
    "orderId": "abc111",
    "amount": 2,
    "name": "item 1"
  },
  {
    "orderId": "abc222",
    "amount": 5,
    "name": "item 2"
  }
]
```

tried like this;

```bash
jq -c '.[]' ./data.json | while read i; do    
    curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
    --json $i
done
```

unfortunately getting this error

```bash
{"message":{"statusCode":400,"message":"Unexpected end of JSON input","error":"Bad Request"},"status":400}

{"message":{"statusCode":400,"message":"Unexpected end of JSON input","error":"Bad Request"},"status":400}
```

however, this works nicely;

```bash
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint' \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \ 
     --json '{
               "orderId":"abc111",
               "amount":2,
               "name": "item 1"
       }'
```

how can I use JSON object in the loop to send as POST payload with CURL?

Comment: Quotes are not optional. `--json "$i"` not `--json $i`

Comment: @pmf, no need for `@json` if you just drop the `-r`. With `-c` and no `-r` you get a separate line per item. (You're right about the need for `read -r`, though).

Comment: wonderful @CharlesDuffy :)